# Weird issue with mouse left and right button not working (but everything else seems fine)

Tags: mouse, mouse-click

I am having a strange problem with my optical mouse
It is a generic mouse with left/right/middle button and scroll wheel
Everything works fine, it is detected properly in different computers (so it is not a software issue), but the left and right buttons do not work when clicked
The problem started with the left mouse button (suddenly stopped working one day), and after a few days, happened to the right one as well
The mouse has faced a lot of rough handling, so I assumed the click button switched were physically damaged. but if I check the button terminals with an Ohmmeter the left/right button switches themselves seem to be making contact when pressed
I assumed some cold solder joints stopped making contact after some period, but looking at the circuit board all the soldering seems to be fine as well
I have no idea what else to, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: In this days the companies make the products not repairable, all my tentative of revival for keyboard/mouse have failed :/ , did you spilled any liquid over it?

Comment: An optical mouse is so cheap that it is not worth trying to fix it.

Comment: nothing spilled, but it has undergone some rough treatment (dropped, beaten, etc). Sometimes randomly the right button seems to suddenly work so I'm also guessing the buttons might have worn out